# why the website content is displaying over the navbar when scrolling

Tags: html, css

the content of the website is displaying over the navigation bar when scrolling
i dont know how to fix it
flksjfjsda lf jjsdfjkldj fkjhdsjk fjkdhfjk lkfjs lkdjflksa fkjhdfjk fd
f jksdfhjksh fakjhjkds hjkh jksdjklhjkf hs
here is the html:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <p class="logo">גכשד יחכי</p>  
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav_links">
                <li><a href="#">אודות</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">שירותים</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">פרוייקטים</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="cta" href="https://support.microsoft.com/he-il/contactus/"><button>צור קשר</button></a>
    </header>
    <div class="intro"></div>
    <main>
        <h1 class="main-text">פסיכולוגית<br /> חינוכית</h1>
        <p class="secendery-text">חשדג גשחכי היא פסיכולוגית חינוכית<br /> העוסקת במקצוע זה למעלה מ20 שנה <br /></p>
        <img src="images/psychology1.png" alt="" class="side-image" />
    </main>
    <div class="card">
        <img src="images/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" >
        <div class="container">
            <h4><b>b</b></h4>
            <p> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the css that refers to the problem:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li, a, button {
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #edf0f1;
}


header {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #24252A;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 10%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}



.nav_links {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}
nav{
    order:2;
}

.cta{
    order:1;
}
.nav_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav_links li a {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav_links li a:hover {
    color:#ddad34;
}




.main-text {
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:absolute;
    top: 32%;
    right: 25%;
    direction: rtl;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: black;
}

.secendery-text {
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%;
    right: 25%;
    direction: rtl;
    color: darkgray;
}

.side-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 5%;
    animation: float 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes float {
    0% {
        transform: translatey(0px);
    }

    50% {
        transform: translatey(-20px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translatey(0px);
    }
}

.
```

if anyone know how can i fix this
please help
thanks

Comment: When this weird words are because the hint with "it seems you post mostly code"
Then take this advice sure and describe your code better and don't write randomly some words

Comment: im sorry im new to this and i dont know what to describe more

Comment: the navigation bar stick to the top when scrolling down but the content of the websit(text and pictures) are displaying over the navigation bar. i want the navigation bar to display over the content of the website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you should add a `z-index` property for the header element. By default if the element `z-index` is not specified it will layer elements by the order of declaration (last html element with `position: absolute/fixed` will overflow previous elements with `position: absolute/fixed`). Try specifying the z-index property for the header
`header { z-index: 100;}`
in the css file.

And for the next time, try to provide a more specific overview of your problem instead of that gibberish.